# Compute deformation gradient in an elasticity problem

Tags: classical-mechanics, tensor-calculus, elasticity, continuum-mechanics

In the problem "finite bending of an incompressible elastic block, [discussed here at pg. 181](https://books.google.it/books?id=f3RrYLujw8oC&pg=PA179&lpg=PA179&dq=Finite%20bending%20of%20an%20incompressible%20elastic%20block&source=bl&ots=hDKzQSjxSv&sig=ACfU3U3fLyBQ9a3XuAl14bfvVHTrmfKs6Q&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi61bzqxLfwAhVGi6QKHcWEBt8Q6AEwCXoECAUQAw#v=onepage&q=Finite%20bending%20of%20an%20incompressible%20elastic%20block&f=false) deformation map is, given $r = f(x)$ and $\theta = g(y)$ two functions which will be determined later:

$$\mathbf{x} = [f(x) \cos(g(y)), f(x) \sin(g(y))] = f(x) \bigl( \cos(g(y)) e_1 + \sin(g(y))e_2 \bigr)$$

The author says that the deformation gradient is $$F = f' e_r \otimes e_1 + (fg') e_\theta \otimes e_2$$

where $e_r = \cos(\theta) e_1 + \sin(\theta) e_2$ and $e_\theta=-\sin(\theta)e_1 + \cos(\theta)e_2$.

**Question**
I don't know the logical steps to write it in that form, i.e. using the dyads $e_r \otimes e_1$. I'll try to write here what I think is the rationale:

- First compute the 4 derivatives, everything w.r.t. the variables $x,y$. They are $$f' \cos(\theta), f'\sin(\theta), -fg' \sin, fg' \cos $$
- Now I know that $F$, the deformation gradient, maps lagrangian elements into eulerian elements, so the basis must be $e_r \otimes e_1$ and $e_\theta \otimes e_2$ **but I don't know why the first term is $f'$ and the other one $fg'$**. **My guess is the following**: they worked out all the partials w.r.t $x,y$: $$f' \cos e_1 \otimes e_1 + fg' \cos e_2 \otimes e_2 + f' \sin e_2 \otimes e_1 - fg'\sin e_1 \otimes e_2 $$

and then he noted:

$$f'(\cos e_1 + \sin e_2) \otimes e_1 = f' e_r \otimes e_1$$ and similarly for the other term

Comment: Is the original configuration in Cartesian coordinates and the deformed one in polar coordinates?

Comment: Yes, precisely @nicoguaro

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\mathbf{x} = f(x_0)\cos(g(y_0))\hat{\mathbf{e}}_1
+ f(x_0)\sin(g(y_0))\hat{\mathbf{e}}_2\, .$$

We can write the deformation gradient as

$$\mathbf{F} = \frac{\partial \mathbf{x}}{\partial x_0}\otimes \hat{\mathbf{e}}_1 + \frac{\partial \mathbf{x}}{\partial y_0}\otimes \hat{\mathbf{e}}_2\, ,$$

or

\begin{align}
\mathbf{F} &= [f' \cos(g)\hat{\mathbf{e}}_1 +
f' \sin(g)\hat{\mathbf{e}}_2]\otimes \hat{\mathbf{e}}_1
+ [- fg' \sin(g)\hat{\mathbf{e}}_1 +
fg' \cos(g)\hat{\mathbf{e}}_2]\otimes \hat{\mathbf{e}}_2\\
&= f'[\cos(g)\hat{\mathbf{e}}_1 +
\sin(g)\hat{\mathbf{e}}_2]\otimes \hat{\mathbf{e}}_1
+ fg'[-\sin(g)\hat{\mathbf{e}}_1 + \cos(g)\hat{\mathbf{e}}_2]\otimes \hat{\mathbf{e}}_2\, .
\end{align}

And we can identify in the brackets $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_r$ and $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_\theta$. Thus

$$\mathbf{F} = \frac{d f(x_0)}{d x_0}\hat{\mathbf{e}}_r\otimes \hat{\mathbf{e}}_1 + f(x_0) \frac{d g(y_0)}{d y_0}\hat{\mathbf{e}}_\theta\otimes \hat{\mathbf{e}}_2\, .$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Why can you write $$\mathbf{F} = \frac{\partial \mathbf{x}}{\partial x_0}\otimes \hat{\mathbf{e}}_1 + \frac{\partial \mathbf{x}}{\partial y_0}\otimes \hat{\mathbf{e}}_2$$? My definition of $F$ is $F= \nabla \mathbf{x}$ only

Comment: @bobinthebox, yes. They are the same thing for Cartesian coordinates. You could expand both of them in terms of the four dyads and see that they are the same. For other coordinate systems it is more convoluted because unit vector would have derivatives different from 0.

Comment: Do you mean the following: 

$$F= \partial_x f_1 e_1 \otimes e_1 + \partial_x f_2 e_2 \otimes e_1 + \partial_y f_1 e_1 \otimes e_2 + \partial_y f_2 e_2 \otimes e_2 = (\partial_x f_1 e_1 + \partial_x f_2 e_2) \otimes e_1 + (\partial_y f_1 e_1+ \partial_y f_2 e_2) \otimes e_2$$ ?

where $f_1,f_2$ are the components of the deformation $x$ (maybe $f$ is not the best choice...)

@nicoguaro

Comment: @bobinthebox, yes. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

In the deformed configuration, the differential position vector between to material points is $$\mathbf{ds}=e_rdr+ e_{\theta}rd\theta=f'e_rdx+(fg')e_{\theta}dy$$ where x and y are the material coordinates of the same pair of material points in the undeformed configuration.  But, this is the same as $$\mathbf{ds}=(f'e_r\otimes e_1+(fg')e_{\theta}\otimes e_2)\centerdot (e_1dx+e_2dy)=\mathbf{F}\centerdot \mathbf{ds_0}$$

Incidentally, isn't this the way we express the transpose of the deformation gradient tensor, rather than the deformation gradient itself?